# AppDomains not needed in Office add-in manifest for external links?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I created a simple Office add-in with a manifest that has no `<AppDomains>` section. I then added the following link to the add-in .html file:

```
<a href="https://www.tutorialrepublic.com">Test</a>
```

When I load the add-in in either Office Online or desktop MS Word and click the link, the addin frame loads the html from www.tutorialrepublic.com.

I would have expected that this would be blocked according to the description here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#specify-domains-you-want-to-open-in-the-add-in-window

Can anyone explain the discrepancy? I found I can also submit to a form and set window.location.href to external domains and they open in the addin iframe, not in a separate window as expected.

Comment: Can someone from Microsoft please confirm if this is expected behavior? It's critical to the functionality of my add-in

Comment: Forgot to tell you when you opened this that I'm investigating with the product team. I can reproduce. I think that documentation page was written when the add-in model was in beta and that it is not up-to-date.

Comment: The product team advises that what you are seeing in Office Online is expected, because the task pane in Office Online is an iFrame and there is no way to check the URLs that an iFrame navigates to against the list in AppDomains. I will revise the documentation to make this clear. You say you get the same behavior in Word desktop. I cannot reproduce that. Could you double check?

Comment: I double checked Word desktop and you are correct, clicking an external link does open a new window. I added an embedded iframe to my add in with an external link, and clicking that link opens the external site inside the iframe.

Comment: OK. I'll make this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation that the OP linked to was in error. It has been corrected. The relevant passage now says:

> When running in Office Online, your task pane can be navigated to any URL. However, in desktop platforms, if your add-in tries to go to
>   a URL in a domain other than the domain that hosts the start page (as
>   specified in the SourceLocation element of the manifest file), that
>   URL opens in a new browser window outside the add-in pane of the
>   Office host application.
>
> To override this (desktop Office) behavior, specify each domain you want to open in the add-in window in the list of domains specified
>   in the AppDomains element of the manifest file. If the add-in tries to
>   go to a URL in a domain that is in the list, then it opens in the task
>   pane in both desktop Office and Office Online. If it tries to go to a
>   URL that isn't in the list, then, in desktop Office, that URL opens in
>   a new browser window (outside the add-in pane).
>
> Note
>
> This behavior applies only to the root pane of the add-in. If there is an iframe embedded in the add-in page, the iframe can be
>   directed to any URL regardless of whether it is listed in AppDomains,
>   even in desktop Office.